# Expose protected member as public with self tyes

Tags: scala, traits, self-type, cake-pattern

I have a trait that representing some module that exposes some public method (think of a service):

```
trait X { 
  def exposeMe: AService = ...
  def keepMeHidden: BService = ...
}
```

Then, I have a `Y` module that requires services from `X`. Clients of `Y` also need one service from `X`. But I don't want them to depend on whole `X`, just on this one service. I would like to like "export" that one service to be public.

```
trait Y { this: X => 
  def exposeMe2: AService = exposeMe
}
```

This works, but is there a way to keep the method name the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Short answer*:

```
trait X { 
  def exposeMe: Int = 12
  def keepMeHidden: Int = 41
}

trait XComponent {
  def x: X
}

trait Y { this: XComponent => 
  def exposeMe: Int = x.exposeMe
}
```

*Update after question edition.*

Problem is that you baked half of cake and then want to extract a layer from this complex component. Right way is to require what you really need:

```
trait Y { this: AServiceComp => 
  def exposeMe: AService = aService.exposeMe
}
```

Where `AServiceComp` implementation could be made with single `AService` implementation or using `new XImpl.exposeMe` (imho the last is bizarre).

Comment: I updated my question. Those methods weren't actual methods but getters for services. And X is already a component/module.